# Postgres: see query used to create materialized view?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working in Postgres 9.4. Is there any way I can see the query that was used to create a materialized view?

Doing:

```
# \d my_view;
```

just shows me the column names and indexes of the view, not the command used to create it. And I can't see anything in [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/rules-materializedviews.html) about this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `select pg_get_viewdef('my_view')` ? (Haven't tested it on a matview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I discover the underlying query of a materialized view I created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25737315/how-do-i-discover-the-underlying-query-of-a-materialized-view-i-created)

Comment: At least in recent versions, you can do `\d+ my_view` although it may abbreviate it. I haven't tried in 9.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is stored in [`pg_matviews`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-matviews.html):

```
select definition
from pg_matview
where matviewname = 'my_view'
and schemaname = 'public';
```

You can also use `pg_get_viewdef()`  as Craig has suggested:

```
select pg_get_viewdef('public.my_view', true);
```